# data.table+r: cumulative mean on a column after sub setting using two other dates columns

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, subset, mean

I have a data.frame DF with 4 columns given below.

```
DF <- structure(list(Ticker = c("ABC", "ABC", "ABC", "ABC","ABC","ABC","ABC", "ABC", "ABC", "ABC", "ABC", "ABC", "ABC", "ABC","ABC","XYZ", "XYZ", "XYZ", "XYZ", "XYZ", "XYZ", "XYZ", "XYZ","XYZ", "XYZ", "XYZ", "XYZ"), `Enter Date` = c("2005-02-08", "2005-02-23","2005-06-07", "2005-06-08", "2005-08-16", "2005-09-07", "2005-11-15","2005-11-17", "2005-12-06", "2005-12-23", "2006-02-09", "2006-02-10","2006-02-15", "2006-02-22", "2006-05-01", "2005-02-22", "2005-02-28","2005-03-01", "2005-03-03", "2005-03-04", "2005-03-11", "2005-03-15","2005-04-04", "2005-04-05", "2005-04-15", "2005-04-22", "2005-04-28"), `Exit Date` = c("2005-03-09", "2005-03-23", "2005-07-06","2005-07-07", "2005-09-14", "2005-10-05", "2005-12-14", "2005-12-16","2006-01-05", "2006-01-25", "2006-03-10", "2006-03-13", "2006-03-16","2006-03-22", "2006-05-30", "2005-03-22", "2005-03-29", "2005-03-30","2005-04-01", "2005-04-04", "2005-04-11", "2005-04-13", "2005-05-02","2005-05-03", "2005-05-13", "2005-05-20","2005-05-26"), Return = c(4.669,4.034, 3.796, -4.059, -11.168, -0.496,-3.597, 3.45, -4.428,1.914, 3.577, 4, 8.451, 5.521, 10.324, 3.104, 0.787,-3.407,-1.441, -4.157, 4.343, 2.827, 0.425, -1.37, -3.175, -11.027,8.144)), .Names = c("Ticker", "Enter Date", "Exit Date", "Return"), row.names = c(NA, 27L), class = "data.frame")
```

I would like to calculate cumulative mean of “Return” column,  where ‘Enter Date’ > ‘Exit Date’ for unique Enter Date and for each Ticker.  I can do it in data.frame way in two steps . The code I used is

```
calCumAve <- function(data,yvar,nSkip)
{
nrs <- seq_len(nrow(data))
CumAve <-  c(rep(NA,nSkip),sapply(nrs[nrs>nSkip],
FUN=function(t){mean(data[data$"Enter Date"[t]> data$"Exit Date", yvar])}))
return(CumAve)
}

DFOut <-  do.call(rbind,lapply(sort(unique(DF$Ticker)), FUN=function(s){
                     sd <- DF[DF$Ticker==s,]
                     sd$AvgRet <- calCumAve(data=sd,yvar="Return",nSkip=4)
                     return(sd)}))
```

The required output is DFOut.

I would like to do this operation in **data.table** way. While applying in data.table, the main problem I’m facing is to sub setting of `Return` column using two date columns. Few things to consider:

(1) In practice there will be 1000 tickers (only 2 in this example, ABC and XYZ) and more than 10 years of daily data.

(2) Do the operation without specifying `nSkip`.  For `Enter Date` <= `Exit Date` it should give NA (not NaN as in row 20:22 in DFOut)

(3) If possible, use column names in sub setting data.table. The given example has four columns but the working data.table will have more than 25 columns, and I need to apply same calculation on several columns by changing `yvar`.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Fyi, in your base R code, the standard way is `lapply(split(DF, DF$Ticker), ...)`

Comment: Thanks @Frank. Will remember.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
dt = as.data.table(DF) # or setDT to convert in place

# cumulative mean, but without the date restriction
dt[, rawAvgRets := cumsum(Return) / (1:.N), by = Ticker]

# find the latest matching date using a rolling merge (assumes sorted dates)
# if you run into > vs >= issues, adjust enter or exit date by a day
dt[, avgRets := dt[dt, rawAvgRets, roll = TRUE,
                   on = c('Ticker' = 'Ticker', 'Exit Date' = 'Enter Date')]]
#    Ticker Enter Date  Exit Date  Return rawAvgRets    avgRets
# 1:    ABC 2005-02-08 2005-03-09   4.669  4.6690000         NA
# 2:    ABC 2005-02-23 2005-03-23   4.034  4.3515000         NA
# 3:    ABC 2005-06-07 2005-07-06   3.796  4.1663333  4.3515000
# 4:    ABC 2005-06-08 2005-07-07  -4.059  2.1100000  4.3515000
# 5:    ABC 2005-08-16 2005-09-14 -11.168 -0.5456000  2.1100000
# 6:    ABC 2005-09-07 2005-10-05  -0.496 -0.5373333  2.1100000
# 7:    ABC 2005-11-15 2005-12-14  -3.597 -0.9744286 -0.5373333
# 8:    ABC 2005-11-17 2005-12-16   3.450 -0.4213750 -0.5373333
# 9:    ABC 2005-12-06 2006-01-05  -4.428 -0.8665556 -0.5373333
#10:    ABC 2005-12-23 2006-01-25   1.914 -0.5885000 -0.4213750
#11:    ABC 2006-02-09 2006-03-10   3.577 -0.2098182 -0.5885000
#12:    ABC 2006-02-10 2006-03-13   4.000  0.1410000 -0.5885000
#13:    ABC 2006-02-15 2006-03-16   8.451  0.7802308 -0.5885000
#14:    ABC 2006-02-22 2006-03-22   5.521  1.1188571 -0.5885000
#15:    ABC 2006-05-01 2006-05-30  10.324  1.7325333  1.1188571
#16:    XYZ 2005-02-22 2005-03-22   3.104  3.1040000         NA
#17:    XYZ 2005-02-28 2005-03-29   0.787  1.9455000         NA
#18:    XYZ 2005-03-01 2005-03-30  -3.407  0.1613333         NA
#19:    XYZ 2005-03-03 2005-04-01  -1.441 -0.2392500         NA
#20:    XYZ 2005-03-04 2005-04-04  -4.157 -1.0228000         NA
#21:    XYZ 2005-03-11 2005-04-11   4.343 -0.1285000         NA
#22:    XYZ 2005-03-15 2005-04-13   2.827  0.2937143         NA
#23:    XYZ 2005-04-04 2005-05-02   0.425  0.3101250 -1.0228000
#24:    XYZ 2005-04-05 2005-05-03  -1.370  0.1234444 -1.0228000
#25:    XYZ 2005-04-15 2005-05-13  -3.175 -0.2064000  0.2937143
#26:    XYZ 2005-04-22 2005-05-20 -11.027 -1.1900909  0.2937143
#27:    XYZ 2005-04-28 2005-05-26   8.144 -0.4122500  0.2937143
#    Ticker Enter Date  Exit Date  Return rawAvgRets    avgRets
```

Comment: **THANKS**  @eddi.  I have learned few data.table tricks in one code. Superb!